# sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in

Tags: python, ssl, aws-lambda, psycopg2, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to run my python code on AWS Lambda to send data to my postgres DB on Heroku. The code works totally fine in my local, but when I test it on AWS, I keep getting this error message:

`[ERROR] OperationalError: sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in`

FYI, I'm running this on python 3.8 with psycopg2, enabling the `sslmode=require` when connecting postgres via psycopg2.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Comment: It sounds as if the installation of libpq on AWS was not built with SSL support, though it could be that on Heroku - there isn't much information to go on here.  There are a number of [existing questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=operationalerror+sslmode+value+require+invalid+when+ssl+support+is+not+compiled+in+site:stackoverflow.com) about this.

Comment: How are you including `psycopg2` in AWS Lambda? Via a Lambda Layer? Are you building it yourself or is it a third-party Lambda layer? As mentioned in the other comment, the `libq` included with `psycopg2` in your Lambda function appears to not have SSL support.